# Positioning with the absolute position

Tags: html, css, css-position

the HTML code below is my HTML markup and i want that the positioning inside this template area is absolute. But when I do this right now, get positioned from the upper left corner but I want that the position (left:0, top:0) is the upper left corner of the class sheet.

Is it possible to do this like that?

```
<div class="sheets" data-bind="foreach: pages">
    <div class="sheet">
        <div class="elements">
            <div data-bind="template: { name: 'image', foreach: Elements }">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position the `<div>` you want it to be offset from using something other than `static`, usually `relative`. In your case:

```
.sheets {
    position: relative;
}
```

should do the trick.

EDIT: Maybe I misread the question. Applying the style to `.sheet` or `.elements` might be more appropriate.

Comment: I agree with you.  You might want to add `.elements { position: absolute; }` as well.

Answer (score 0):

To make elements within a parent element absolutely positioned relative to the parent element (such that 0,0 is the top-left corner of the parent element,) you need to create a new positioning context by setting the parent element to `position:relative;`

If you want your `<div class="sheet">` element to be the new positioning context then do this:

```
.sheet
{
    position:relative;
}
```

This will achieve what you want.

EDIT: for more information, check out this [article on the differences between CSS positioning values](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) and [absolute positioning inside relative positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

Use position relative for class sheet and position absolute for it's children.

```
.sheet {
position:relative;
}
.elements {
position:absolute; 
top:0; 
left:0;
}
```